# How to optimize my Java code for using Java 7 switch?

Tags: java, split

I have a query is that I have a string that I get through a param, the issue is that the split I realize you do not know if it's the best, but the idea was to separate these value chains that interest me, and then compare them.

```
public class TestSplit {

    public static final String CODIGO_BUSCAR = "001";
    public static final String CODIGO_NUEVO = "002";
    public static final String CODIGO_MODIFICAR = "003";
    public static final String CODIGO_ELIMINAR = "004";     
    public static final String CODIGO_CONSULTAR = "006";



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        boolean mostrarBotonNuevo = false;
        boolean mostrarBotonModificar = false;
        boolean mostrarBotonConsultar = false;
        boolean mostrarBotonEliminar = false;
        boolean mostrarBotonBuscar = false;

        String key = "{javax.faces.partial.ajax=true, javax.faces.source=j_idt88:linkAjax, javax.faces.partial.execute=@all, javax.faces.partial.render=mensajesGrowl, j_idt88:linkAjax=j_idt88:linkAjax, parametroAccion={javax.faces.partial.ajax=true, javax.faces.source=j_idt80:j_idt82:linkAjax, javax.faces.partial.execute=@all, javax.faces.partial.render=mensajesGrowl, j_idt80:j_idt82:linkAjax=j_idt80:j_idt82:linkAjax, parametroAccion={menuForm=menuForm, j_idt46_activeIndex=0, javax.faces.ViewState=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, vdesOpcForm=menuItemCotizaciones, j_idt46:j_idt55=j_idt46:j_idt55, menuItemCotizaciones005=menuItemCotizaciones005, menuItemCotizaciones006=menuItemCotizaciones006, j_idt46:j_idt55_menuid=2_9, menuItemCotizaciones003=menuItemCotizaciones003, menuItemCotizaciones004=menuItemCotizaciones004, menuItemCotizaciones001=menuItemCotizaciones001, menuItemCotizaciones002=menuItemCotizaciones002}, principalForm=principalForm, idSeleccionoRegistro=false, j_idt120:input=, j_idt124:select_focus=, j_idt124:select_input=, j_idt129:select_focus=, j_idt129:select_input=, j_idt134:calendar_input=, j_idt137:calendar_input=, javax.faces.ViewState=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}, principalForm=principalForm, j_idt96:input=, j_idt100:input=0, javax.faces.ViewState=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...";

        String keyFormat [] = key.split("=");
        for(String value : keyFormat) {
            System.out.println("--> "+value);
            if(value.endsWith(CODIGO_BUSCAR)) {
                mostrarBotonBuscar = true;
            }
            if(value.endsWith(CODIGO_NUEVO)) {
                mostrarBotonNuevo = true;
            }
            if(value.endsWith(CODIGO_MODIFICAR)) {
                mostrarBotonModificar = true;
            }
            if(value.endsWith(CODIGO_ELIMINAR)) {
                mostrarBotonEliminar = true;
            }
            if(value.endsWith(CODIGO_CONSULTAR)) {
                mostrarBotonConsultar = true;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("--> mostrarBotonBuscar: "+mostrarBotonBuscar+" mostrarBotonNuevo: "+mostrarBotonNuevo+
                           " mostrarBotonModificar: "+mostrarBotonModificar+" mostrarBotonEliminar: "+mostrarBotonEliminar+
                           " mostrarBotonConsultar: "+mostrarBotonConsultar);


    }

}
```

Basically what I do is use the slipt to separate strings and compare whether the value ends in **"001"**, **"002"**, **"003"**, **"004"** and **"006"**, what other details do not matter, and then they meet is activate the corresponding boolean state.

I was thinking to use a **switch** or **while** operator to optimize my code, if anyone can give me a guidance to improve my code, because as noticing the loop is comparing each chain, the idea is to compare each and finish the loop.

Comment: Extract the last 3 characters then use switch on that.

Comment: If I do it will do the most optimal method of endsWith chain ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `while` even fits here. `switch` will not do any good either (rather leave it as it is, or better, change `ifs` to `else-ifs`.. But I can give a better idea, that involves none of them. Just make use of `||` operator. That will require changing your `for` loop to something like:

```
for(String value : keyFormat) {
    System.out.println("--> "+value);
    mostrarBotonBuscar = mostrarBotonBuscar || value.endsWith(CODIGO_BUSCAR);
    mostrarBotonNuevo = mostrarBotonNuevo || value.endsWith(CODIGO_NUEVO);
    mostrarBotonModificar = mostrarBotonModificar || value.endsWith(CODIGO_MODIFICAR);
    mostrarBotonEliminar = mostrarBotonEliminar || value.endsWith(CODIGO_ELIMINAR);
    mostrarBotonConsultar = mostrarBotonConsultar || value.endsWith(CODIGO_CONSULTAR);
}
```

That's it. Nothing else you need. Moreover it will also stop evaluating the corresponding `endsWith()` methods once the flag is set to `true`.

Comment: If I find it faster to make a substring for each string and then be comparing each conditional.

Answer (score 0):

**Thus concern with doing subtring and switch ....**

```
public class TestSplit {

    public static final String CODIGO_BUSCAR = "001";
    public static final String CODIGO_NUEVO = "002";
    public static final String CODIGO_MODIFICAR = "003";
    public static final String CODIGO_ELIMINAR = "004";     
    public static final String CODIGO_CONSULTAR = "006";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        boolean mostrarBotonNuevo = false;
        boolean mostrarBotonModificar = false;
        boolean mostrarBotonConsultar = false;
        boolean mostrarBotonEliminar = false;
        boolean mostrarBotonBuscar = false;

        String key = "{javax.faces.partial.ajax=true, javax.faces.source=j_idt88:linkAjax, javax.faces.partial.execute=@all, javax.faces.partial.render=mensajesGrowl, j_idt88:linkAjax=j_idt88:linkAjax, parametroAccion={javax.faces.partial.ajax=true, javax.faces.source=j_idt80:j_idt82:linkAjax, javax.faces.partial.execute=@all, javax.faces.partial.render=mensajesGrowl, j_idt80:j_idt82:linkAjax=j_idt80:j_idt82:linkAjax, parametroAccion={menuForm=menuForm, j_idt46_activeIndex=0, javax.faces.ViewState=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, vdesOpcForm=menuItemCotizaciones, j_idt46:j_idt55=j_idt46:j_idt55, menuItemCotizaciones005=menuItemCotizaciones005, menuItemCotizaciones006=menuItemCotizaciones006, j_idt46:j_idt55_menuid=2_9, menuItemCotizaciones003=menuItemCotizaciones003, menuItemCotizaciones004=menuItemCotizaciones004, menuItemCotizaciones001=menuItemCotizaciones001, menuItemCotizaciones002=menuItemCotizaciones002}, principalForm=principalForm, idSeleccionoRegistro=false, j_idt120:input=, j_idt124:select_focus=, j_idt124:select_input=, j_idt129:select_focus=, j_idt129:select_input=, j_idt134:calendar_input=, j_idt137:calendar_input=, javax.faces.ViewState=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}, principalForm=principalForm, j_idt96:input=, j_idt100:input=0, javax.faces.ViewState=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...";

        String keyFormat [] = key.split("=");
        for(String value : keyFormat) {
            int size = value.length();
            if(size > 3) {
                String vcodIdeObj = value.substring(size-3, size);
                switch (vcodIdeObj) {       
                    case CODIGO_BUSCAR:
                        mostrarBotonBuscar = true;
                        break;
                    case CODIGO_NUEVO:
                        mostrarBotonNuevo = true;
                        break;
                    case CODIGO_MODIFICAR:
                        mostrarBotonModificar = true;
                        break;
                    case CODIGO_ELIMINAR:
                        mostrarBotonEliminar = true;
                        break;  
                    case CODIGO_CONSULTAR:
                        mostrarBotonConsultar = true;
                        break;                      
                }               
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Please validate my code, thanks.**

Comment: The calculation of the split in the chain also is worrying me, it's the only way I could find to separate the strands, according to the data I require.